# Network dataset not being built (greyed out) using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst, network-dataset

I am trying to build a network dataset on ArcGIS Pro using a shapefile that contains polylines for different functional classification roads. I have added "length" of the polylines and "speed limit" for the roads in the shapefile attribute table. Later, I tried to build a network dataset with Time and Distance costs so, I can use it for OD matrix and routing.

But the problem is after "Building" it, the network looks greyed out and clicking on the layer does not bring Explore Network tab. After trying to create a OD Matrix based on this network dataset, it says the network is not properly built or does not show any value for TIME or Distance.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried converting the shapefile to geodatabase? Not sure which version you are using 2.8 has some improvements. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/how-to-create-a-usable-network-dataset.htm

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/network-dataset-build-errors.htm)